# SortedSet.Contains gives error "at least one object must implement ICombarable"

Tags: c#, icomparable, sortedset

I have two SortedSets:

```
SortedSet<SortedSet<int>> sset1 = new SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>();
SortedSet<SortedSet<int>> sset2 = new SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>();
```

Later on I check I make a new Sorted set:

```
 SortedSet<int> newSset = MethodThatReturnsSortedSet();
```

Now I want to check if sset1 and sset2 contain newSset:

```
if (!sset1.Contains(newSset) && !sset2.Contains(newSset))  <--error on this line
   {
       sset1.Add(next);
       //some more code
   }
```

So the error I get is Argument Exception, "at least one of these objects must implement IComparable.

I have looked at other questions with the same problem, but in their case they want to compare their own classes. I am just checking if a certain item is in a Set. So yea..I have no idea how to solve this, any pointers?

Comment: Why do you use a SortedSet of SortedSets? Would another collection do as well that does not need an IComparable as its content?

Comment: I suppose I could change them to a Hashset

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `SortedSet` of `SortedSet`s unless you specify a custom comparer, because `SortedSet` does not implement `IComparable` in itself.

Whenever you use the type `SortedSet<X>`, the set is organized in increasing order based on `X`, so `X` must be `IComparable<X>` or just `IComparable`, or else the `SortedSet<X>` must be created with the constructor overload which allows you to give a custom object of type `IComparer<X>`.

Which of these two `SortedSet<int>` comes first:

```
{ 3, 8, 25, }
```

or:

```
{ 3, 7, 9, 58, 12345678, }
```

ADDITION: With no answer to the above, I assumed you wanted lexicographic comparison, which seems somewhat natural. I wrote this class:

```
class LexicographicComparer : Comparer<SortedSet<int>>
{
    public override int Compare(SortedSet<int> x, SortedSet<int> y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return Default.Compare(x, y);

        int firstDifference = x.Zip(y, Comparer<int>.Default.Compare)
            .Where(n => n != 0).FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstDifference != 0)
            return firstDifference;

        return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x.Count, y.Count);
    }
}
```

That class inherits from `Comparer<>` class and implements `IComparer<>` interface because of that. You use it when you construct your "nested" `SortedSet`, for example:

```
LexicographicComparer lc = new LexicographicComparer();
SortedSet<SortedSet<int>> sset1 = new SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>(lc);
SortedSet<SortedSet<int>> sset2 = new SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>(lc);
```